# SharePoint 2013 server Setup error. Unable to proceed due to the following error(s): This product requires Microsoft .Net Framework 4.5

Tags: sharepoint-server, installation, .net

I found that this problem occurs because the SharePoint Setup and Project Server Setup programs do not recognize the .NET Framework 4.6, 4.6.1, or 4.6.2 as a supported version of the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft released Hotfix for this issue. Kindly check below URL for the provided resolution .

**https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3087184**

OR you can also refer below blog

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2016/09/14/sharepoint-2013-installer-now-supports-net-framework-4-6-and-above/

Hope it helps!!